# Transfer a fixed value of ether

Tags: ether, remix, address.transfer

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;
contract Test {
    address one;

function Test(address _one) public {
    one = _one;
}

function send1() public payable {
    one.transfer(10);
}

function send2() public payable {
    require(msg.value > 0);
    one.transfer(msg.value);
}

function get() public view returns (address) {
    return one;
}
```

}

I'm trying do a simple smart contract in remix to transfer a fixed value of ether to the address 'one'. The funcion send2() is working but the function send1 is not. 
Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting when executing send1()?

Comment: transact to browser/TestTransfer2.sol:Test.send1 errored: VM error: revert.
revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
 Debug the transaction to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the function is actually working, but you are not noticing the ether being sent.

```
function send1() public payable {
    one.transfer(10);
}
```

The function above will transfer 10 wei. If you want to transfer 10 ether you should do:

```
function send1() public payable {
    one.transfer(10 ether);
}
```

Make sure that the contract has that kind of balance or that the function call is being passed such amount of value.

Comment: I tried that but is still not working. I think is because the message value is zero.

Comment: If the value is 0, are you making sure the contract has enough balance before calling the function?